# Form validation not identifying blank inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have create a Login form with js validation. but when i clicked submit button it didn't get any validations errors. i cant find what the error is. Here is my code html form and js file.

I expect the output as enter email and password but it didn't display any validations.

This is my HTML form.

```js
$("#loginForm").on("submit", function() {
  var email = $("login_email");
  var pass = $("login_pass");
  var status = false;


  if (email.val() == "") {
    email.addClass("border-danger");
    $("#e_error").html("<span class='text-danger'>Enter valid email..</span>");
    status = false;
  } else {
    email.removeClass("border-danger");
    $("#e_error").html("");
    status = true;
  }
  if (pass.val() == "") {
    pass.addClass("border-danger");
    $("#p_error").html("<span class='text-danger'>Enter password..</span>");
    status = false;
  } else {
    pass.removeClass("border-danger");
    $("#p_error").html("");
    status = true;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="loginForm" onsubmit="return false" autocomplete="off">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="login_email" id="login_email" placeholder="Enter email">
    <small id="e_error" class="form-text text-muted">ddd</small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="login_pass" id="login_pass" placeholder="Password">
    <small id="p_error" class="form-text text-muted"></small>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
  <span><a href="register.php">Register</a></span>
</form>
```

So, can you gyes please help me to fix this.. Thank you !

Comment: typo `$("#login_email");`

Comment: If we are using the Id in the jquery we need to put # before the Id name. Take the reference from the link https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many mistakes,

Firstly No need to use: onsubmit="return false" in form, that's return by event handler,
like

```
$("#loginForm").on("submit", function() {
    var status=true;

    return status;
});
```

second: 
use

```
var email = $("#login_email");
var pass = $("#login_pass");
```

For check blank space validation check:

```
if($.trim(email.val()) != ""){

}
```

And In the final You are using Wrong why as

1st condition is false, then status will false, means form should not submit, But according to your condition, It will submit if next condition will true, as password not null then status will check again to true, then form will submit, event email null, So please use status on input fields like data-status or by .error call or something else

And best way you can use jQuery validation
https://jqueryvalidation.org/

change status for false conditions only not for true,

```
$("#loginForm").on("submit", function() {
    var status=true;

    if($.trim(email.val()) != ""){

    }else{
        status=false;
    }
    return status;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You've missed the `#` on the selector :

```
    var email = $("login_email");
    var pass = $("login_pass");
```

Should be :

```
    var email = $("#login_email");
    var pass = $("#login_pass");
```

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you access an element by its ID you should have # prefix to the selector. Here is your corrected code, please check .

```js
    $("#loginForm").on("submit", function() {
      var email = $("#login_email");
      var pass = $("#login_pass");
      var status = false;


      if (email.val() == "") {
        email.addClass("border-danger");
        $("#e_error").html("<span class='text-danger'>Enter valid email..</span>");
        status = false;
      } else {
        email.removeClass("border-danger");
        $("#e_error").html("");
        status = true;
      }
      if (pass.val() == "") {
        pass.addClass("border-danger");
        $("#p_error").html("<span class='text-danger'>Enter password..</span>");
        status = false;
      } else {
        pass.removeClass("border-danger");
        $("#p_error").html("");
        status = true;
      }
    })
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <form id="loginForm" onsubmit="return false" autocomplete="off">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="login_email" id="login_email" placeholder="Enter email">
        <small id="e_error" class="form-text text-muted">ddd</small>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="login_pass" id="login_pass" placeholder="Password">
        <small id="p_error" class="form-text text-muted"></small>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
      <span><a href="register.php">Register</a></span>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery selectors allow you to select and manipulate HTML element(s).

jQuery selectors are used to "find" (or select) HTML elements based on their name, id, attributes etc.

Here you are using id to call the elements
Thus, as mentioned by above answer you need to use

You've missed the # on the selector :

```
var email = $("login_email");
var pass = $("login_pass");
```

to select the elements.

For other selectors if you are to use in future you can visit
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp